# What are the key components to compare and contrast when deciding between hardtail mountain bikes?

Tags: parts, cannondale, trek

Trek Stache 7 vs Cannondale Beast of the East 2

I'm trying to decide between what seems to me as almost two identical bikes.
One is made by Cannondale while the other is a Trek.

They are both priced the same.
What are some of the key components that I should compare to help me make my decision?

Any suggestions or recommendations are welcome?

I’m open to all Ideas.

Thank you all so much in advance.

Comment: Have you ridden them? The first thing is that they have different wheel sizes in this case, which can give different handling.

Comment: I wish I had the ability to ride both of them.  Would you prefer a smaller wheel for a lower center of gravity?  Thank you

Comment: Two pretty major points between those two are that the Cannondale has their proprietary offset hub, which means the frame can only take a very small number of hubs/wheels and few shops are going to have one just sitting there if you ever need to replace a wheel on short notice. Meanwhile the Cannondale has an RS Reba fork with among the best parts availability/support ever, while the Trek has a Manitou.

Comment: Seems kinda ridiculous to buy a 2000+ dollar bicycle without trying it.

Comment: I couldn't agree more.  If I had a Trek dealer with a Stache 7 in stock I would totally take it for a spin.  Thank you for all the info.  The dealer never mentioned anything about the Cannondale proprietary offset hub.

Comment: I don't understand. You seem to want to spend a huge amount of money on a bike without having any idea what might make a bike worth so much money.

Comment: ...and this is the problem with buying on-line.  Some things its just not worth doing, shoes, cars, bikes should not be bought sight-unseen.

Comment: I think the color is important ...

Comment: Its very easy to advocate always testing a bike before riding it, but in some cases its just not practical.  I'd have to drive 100's of miles each way to get a proper test ride on either of of these models.  And i'm sure we can all agree that a car-park test ride is pretty useless for a MTB.

Comment: Sure, but these bikes are *expensive* -- even flying out to a different location where you can test ride them would be a small portion of the cost. Plus, if they aren't available locally, offloading one if you don't like it may be difficult. At the minimum you need to get reviews from people who have tried one (and preferably both) and are preferably familiar with the type of riding you intend to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before outnumbering some key points I usually look when I want to buy a bike, I will tell you this: Ride them both. Form an opinion for each one and buy the one you think that comes better to you.

1. Compare their peripherials (suspension, drivetrain, brakes etc). Check what their manufacturer made them for and the warranty provided. If you have two bikes having drivetrain from the same manufacturer, it is wise you choose the one that might have a better series on (why get sram x9 if you can have xx for example).
2. What is the frame warranty from the manufacturer?
3. Make sure you know what are you spending your money to. Both bikes you are looking at are expensive xc bikes with some top peripherials. What discipline do you really want to ride? Do you need something that expensive? Are you a competitor, or just a fan of mtb?
4. What is your experience level? Beginner or pro? Spending a huge amount of money on a bike as a beginner is wrong. Learning and evolving on a reliable, yet not top of the class bike, will make you a better rider.

I suppose you are a beginner. If you are not oriented to racing xc, get a cheaper bike. Once you have learned technical stuff and have concluded to the ride discipline you prefer, get a serious bike.

Comment: Did you look at the bikes?  Neither of them have any top peripherals, nor are they XC focussed, and you certainly wouldn't be racing on them.  I would have said with the exception of being slightly pricey, they would both make excellent first mountain bikes.

Comment: Yes, i did. They might not be the +7.000$ ultra racing toys, but they are considerably better than the average -1000$ scott scale or the trek superfly. It is almost twice the money. My firm belief is, if we are talking about someone who is new to mtb and making his/her early steps, they should start with a cheap, yet reliable bike. Not only they will learn better what is that they really want to ride, they will also have an extra 1000$ saved to get a more suitable bike. That is my opinion. That's why a buyer must know what he wants and what his level is.

Comment: @ChrisTsiakoulas, both Trek Stache 7 and Cannondale Beast of the East 2 are advertised for _trail_ and not XC. Trek Superfly & Procaliber and Cannondale F-Si are designed for cross-country.

Comment: Having ridden lots of mountain bikes in a bunch o different disciplines, i can assure you all those bikes are capable of riding more than what they are advertised about. And thats how it has to be. I cant think of anyyhing better on a bike than the flexibility to inttoduce its rider to another discipline without encountering difficulties. If the rider is willing to get dirty, these bikes will follow.